# Can we run value analysis in Frama-C on a C file that does not have the main function?

Tags: frama-c

When running Frama-C on a C file without the main function, I got errors.
Is there any option to run Frama-C value analysis on such C files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 6 of the [user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/user-manual-Fluorine-20130601.pdf), which discusses global analysis options, answers your question. Unsurprisingly, the relevant option is called `-main`...